# Performance of deserializing XML in IIS

Tags: xml, performance, iis, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm looking to make use of some basic xml files, most no more than 100kb and serialize/deserialize them into objects. This would be done using the .NET frameworks built in serialize attributes/classes, in lieu of holding them in a database.

My concern if the site is being hit (on a well balanced web farm) multiple times, could there be possible performance issues? The amount of data and number of objects/fields coming back isn't very large, maybe 10 objects - and they would be on powerful virtual servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of your applications will always be a matter of balance between your code and your hardware. Because you are building a web application, it is inherently necessary that big workloads are handled with multi-threading, so you can have multiple background threads performing time-expensive jobs, avoiding slow performance on the threads that handle your web requests. However your escenario doesn't look so much of a problem, not even to a tipical laptop nowadays, be sure that you don't overengineer your applications when simple task can be well-handled by your current servers.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't say without knowing more about your environment but I do know that processor cycles are a lot more expensive than 100KB of memory. How often will these XML files be changed? If it wouldn't be often you could look into just storing the deserialized objects in memory since it's only 100KB.

Comment: They wont be changed often (so I wanted to save database hits across a slow network). Do you mean storing them in the Cache object?

Comment: That works, or a singleton object. Whichever you're more comfortable with. A singleton might be simpler to include code which will check the last time it updated the object with the last update value of the XML file so you can have that all happen behind the scenes.